# Incremental load in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, incremental-load

I have a source table that has some millions of rows and the job runs the SSIS package to load the data daily.

Now the daily job is taking for hours to run the entire load due to several rows.

I want to just do the incremental logic on the SSIS package I run.

I just want to capture the records that are modified/added on that day without reading the entire data.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: you need to provide a bit more information, for example, loading millions of rows would normally take seconds, if done against a table with no indices, triggers, etc. what does the package do that takes hours? are the source and target on the same server? is the source a table or a query? how does the source table indicate new/modified rows (is there an added/modified date column); if yes, you can?

Comment: _modified/added on that day_ Do rows get deleted?

Comment: The source and target are on different servers. There is a created date column in source but no modified date. The source is a table. The rows don’t get deleted

Comment: Do rows ever get updated?  If so and there is no marker to indicate an update has occurred then you really are stuck with doing a full load each time.